# Android - How to set value of ArrayList to TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

i have a problem here.
I've ArrayList from the result of my parser class. then i wanna put that value (value from ArrayList) to TextView.

here is the work i've done till now.
I create TextView on my main.xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/deskripsi" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"
    />
```

and here at my onCreate Method, i initialized the Text View

```
desk = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.deskripsi);
```

and then i tried to parser the KML document from google map and at the Node Placemark i put its value to ArrayList, here my code

```
ArrayList<String> pathName = new ArrayList<String>();
Object[] objPlace;

//Parser Node Placemark
NodeList nlPlace = doc.getElementsByTagName("Placemark");
        for(int p = 0; p < nlPlace.getLength(); p++){
            Node rootPlace = nlPlace.item(p);
            NodeList itemPlace = rootPlace.getChildNodes();
            for(int y = 0; y < itemPlace.getLength(); y++){
                Node placeStringNode = itemPlace.item(y);
                NodeList place = placeStringNode.getChildNodes();
                //valueName = nameList.item(0).getNodeValue().toString() + "+";
                pathName.add(place.item(0).getNodeValue());
            }
    }

objPlace = pathName.toArray();

desk.setText("");
for (int j = 0; j < objPlace.length; j++){
    desk.append("Deskripsi:\n" + objPlace[j].toString() + "\n");
}
```

but when itried to run its to my emulator and real device, i get an error. here's my LogCat
[image]

please help me, and sorry for my english >_<

Comment: which line in this code is 107

Comment: Why do u put the arraylist to object[]?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this instead; use `pathName` directly in the for loop...

```
desk.setText("");
for (int j = 0; j < pathName.size(); j++){
    desk.append("Deskripsi:\n" + pathName.get(j) + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put the line

```
 objPlace[] = new Object[pathName.size()]
```

before

```
objPlace = pathName.toArray();
```

and check output otherwise do this way

```
 desk.setText("");

 for (int j = 0; j < pathName.size(); j++){
     desk.append("Deskripsi:\n" + pathName.get(j) + "\n");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ii is caused by `NullPointerException`, that means some needs parameters and you have passed a null value to it.
Based on your code it might be around `desk.setText("");`. Try inserting a space or some value into it and run.

Comment: He got RunTimeException not NullPointerException

Comment: To quote the error posted above "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize your array...  objPlace[] is a null array.

You need to do something like:

```
objPlace[] = new Object[arraysizenumber]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks my fren. im still not really well on using Object[]. then i used this code for solving my problem

```
String strPlace[] = (String[])pathName.toArray(new String[pathName.size()]);

desk.setText("");
        for (int j = 0; j < strPlace.length; j++){
            desk.append("Deskripsi:\n" + strPlace[j] + "\n");
        }
```

Thanks for userSeven7s, flameaddict and khan for trying to help me.
nice to know u all :)